# Haskell maps returning a monad

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads, option-type

The lookup function in Data.Map and Data.IntMap currently return values wrapped in Maybe with
the type signature

```
lookup  :: Ord  k => k -> Map  k a -> Maybe  a
```

It used to have the more general type of

```
lookup  :: (Monad  m, Ord  k) => k -> Map  k a -> m a
```

I realize the former likely reduces the need of extra type specification, but the latter would make it much more general and allow lookup to be used in list comprehensions. Is there any way to mimic this behavior with the newer version, or would I have to use an older version of the library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don's `lift` converts `Maybe`'s elements to their general `Monad` counterparts, so perhaps it should be named `convert` or `generalize` or something;-)

If you just want to use `lookup` mainly in list comprehensions and other monads that implement a `fail`, you could also make use of the mapping of pattern match failure to `fail`:

```
Prelude> [ v | Just v <- return $ lookup "hi" [("ho","silver")] ]
[]
Prelude> [ v | Just v <- return $ lookup "ho" [("ho","silver")] ]
["silver"]

Prelude> do Just v <- return $ lookup "hi" [("ho","silver")] ; print v
*** Exception: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at <interactive>:1:3-8)
Prelude> do Just v <- return $ lookup "ho" [("ho","silver")] ; print v
"silver"
```

Comment: This illustrates perfectly why use of fail is bad: it is almost always a program terminating exception. Not what you want when looking up in maps.

Comment: Well, I said "monads that implement a fail", didn't I?-) `error` is undefined is not implemented. I just wanted to illustrate that case, too.

Personally, I use pattern match fail in do-blocks when the monad is also a `MonadPlus` and implements `fail` as `mzero`. That is when this technique is most useful.

Answer (score 21):

> the latter would make it much more general and allow lookup to be used in list comprehensions

The latter is also more unsafe, as the majority of monad classes define fail as `error`. That is, the common case of not finding an element in the Map is a program-terminating error for most monads. That, coupled with the increased likelihood of the wrong type context being inferred, means we tend to discourage the 'monadic fail return' style now.

> Is there any way to mimic this behavior with the newer version

Indeed there is! Simply lift Maybe a into Monad a, like so:

```
lift :: Monad m => Maybe a -> m a
lift Nothing  = fail "you die now"
lift (Just a) = return a
```

And now you can write, e.g. `lift . lookup`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Don. That's much more concise than what I came up with.

Comment: It might make sense to consider updating this answer once the next major version of `base` comes out. It's looking like `fail` is finally leaving `Monad`, perhaps landing in a new `MonadFail`.

Answer (score 5):

For the specific case of the list monad, the simplest solution is to use `maybeToList`:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Maybe -- Note: Use "import Data.Maybe" in a program file

Data.Maybe> [ v | v <- maybeToList $ lookup "hi" [("ho","silver")] ]
[]
Data.Maybe> [ v | v <- maybeToList $ lookup "ho" [("ho","silver")] ]
["silver"]
```