# The Maybe result from Map.lookup is not type checking with my Monad Transformer stack

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads, monad-transformers, option-type

I am going though the following paper: [Monad Transformers Step by Step](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf). In section 2.1 "Converting to Monadic Style", a function is converted to return `Value` in the `Eval1` monad. This part of the function doesn't make sense to me:

```
eval1 env (Var n) = Map.lookup n env
```

The result of that will be `Maybe Value` however the function's type signature is:

```
eval1 :: Env → Exp → Eval1 Value
```

The function is failing to type check, and the error seems obvious to me.  Yet the author specifically states that this will work:

> ... the Var case does not need a fromJust call anymore: The reason is that Map.lookup is defined to work within any monad by simply calling the monad’s fail function – this fits nicely with our monadic formulation here.

The signature for Map.lookup does not look like it is designed to work with any monad:

```
lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a
```

Is this paper out of date or am I missing something?  If the paper is in fact out of date, why was `lookup` changed to only work with `Maybe`.

Thanks!

Comment: It's out of date (since `containers` version 0.2.0.0, from 2008). This method was briefly popular but then went out of style again. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030767/haskell-maps-returning-a-monad), in particular Don Stewart's answer.

Comment: The next time you wonder if an interface has changed, you can usually get the answer by looking at old and new versions on Hackage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your tutorial is from 2006. It uses [a very old version of `Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html#v:lookup) in which `lookup`'s type indeed was:

```
lookup :: (Monad m, Ord k) => k -> Map k a -> m a
```

I reckon the change happened because `fail` is widely considered to be a wart in the `Monad` class. Returning a `Maybe a` makes a lookup failure explicit and manageable. Making it implicit by hiding it behind `fail` just to have a slightly more convenient type is quite dirty IMO. (See also [the question linked to by Ørjan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030767/haskell-maps-returning-a-monad).)

You can use this adapted version of `lookup` to follow along the tutorial:

```
fallibleLookup :: (Ord k, Monad m) => k -> Map.Map k a -> m a
fallibleLookup k = maybe (fail "fallibleLookup: Key not found") pure . Map.lookup k
```

Note that [with the upcoming release of GHC 8.8](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/migration/8.8#base-41300) the proper constraint to use on `m` will be `MonadFail` rather than `Monad`.